# I do not quite understand this difference in limits

Tags: limits, absolute-value

According it my study material:

$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac {x}{|x|}= -1$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-} \frac {1}{|x|}= \infty$

Why does $\lim_{x\to0^-} \frac {1}{|x|}\ne -\infty$ as 1 still devided by a negative number?

Comment: $\lvert x\rvert$ is not negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x<0$, then $|x|=-x>0$. Therefore $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{|x|} = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{-x} = - \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} = -(-\infty)=+\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value of a negative number is a positive number, i.e.
$$
|x| = \left\{ \begin{array}{l l}
x, & x > 0\\
-x, & x < 0
\end{array} \right.
$$
so this means that
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^- } \frac{1}{|x|} = \frac{1}{-x}  =\infty, \ x < 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that despite $x$ being negative, $|x|$ is still *defined* to  be a strictly nonnegative number. Therefore you are actually dividing a positive number by a positive number, giving $\infty$ rather than $-\infty$.